# How to get ordered results with WPQuery

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've got an `events` custom post type and I'm trying to order them but nothing I do seems to change their order.  I'm using Advanced Custom Fields, so I'm setting the `meta_key` to the attribute I care about.

Does anything look off about this query?

```php
function events_archive( $query ) {
  if( is_admin() ) {
    return $query;
  }

  if( $query->is_post_type_archive('events')  && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('meta_key', 'start_date');
    $query->set('orderby',  'meta_value');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
                                  array(
                                    'key' => 'start_date',
                                    'value' => date('Ymd'),
                                    'type' => 'DATE',
                                    'compare' => '>=',
                                    ) 
                                 )
    );
    return $query;
  }
}
```

I'm getting results, but I've noticed that I can swap `$query->set('order', 'ASC')` with `$query->set('order', 'DESC');` and it doesn't change the order.

I've seen some similar SO posts that recommend using `$query->set('orderby',  'meta_value_num');` instead of `$query->set('orderby',  'meta_value');` but that doesn't seem to have any effect o the ordering.

Any suggestions on how to get ordering to work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the meta value as a date as well as setting the meta type.  When you do the actual meta query, you are specifying the date for which to query posts, but you are not telling the query to order them by the date necessarily.

```
function events_archive( $query ) {
  if( is_admin() ) {
    return $query;
  }

  if( $query->is_post_type_archive('events')  && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('meta_key', 'start_date');
    $query->set('meta_type', 'DATE');
    $query->set('orderby',  'meta_value_date');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
                                  array(
                                    'key' => 'start_date',
                                    'value' => date('Ymd'),
                                    'type' => 'DATE',
                                    'compare' => '>=',
                                    ) 
                                 )
    );
    return $query;
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense but it has no effect on the order to results.

Comment: Not sure if this would have an effect but does your start_date field also have a time?  Or just a date?  And what is that date format?

Comment: Also check your ACF field settings to make sure the proper date format is set there.

Comment: The `start_date` field is only a date.

Comment: What's odd is that if I put my query in the events archive template and run it there, the events are ordered correctly.  The `orderby` attribute is only ignored when the code above is run as part of `pre_get_posts`.  I can't think of why that'd be.

Comment: I see.  That is probably your issue right there.  I was unaware you were trying to put this somewhere else.  You "is_post_type_archive" setting is likely the reason.  If you remove that, and simply add the post_type as part of the query array that should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ordering happens alphabetically but you're passing it a number (a formatted date as `'Ymd'`). Try adding `meta_value_num` instead of `meta_value` in your `orderby` clause. [Here's more info on that](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a custom post type, you should use `meta_key` instead of `key`in your array, like

```
'meta_key' => 'start_date',
```

and

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC',
```

for the ordering (or `ASC`, whichever you need)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this did not affect the order.